# StringContent(json) vs JsonContent.Create(obj)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

This works:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
var content = new StringContent(json);
var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("", content);
// 200 OK
```

This doesn't:

```
var content = JsonContent.Create(obj);
var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("", content);
// 500 Internal Server Error
```

Does JsonContent serialize or encode the content differently?
Are there serialization options that might make the second example behave like the first?

I know I can use the first, but I am trying to understand why the 2nd isn't working.

UPDATE: How is obj defined?

```
var obj = new AccountLookupService.GetUserOnlineProfileRequest
{
    ContractAccountNumber = "100087751101",
    Address = new ServiceAddress
    {
        HouseNumber = string.Empty,
        StreetName = string.Empty,
        HouseNumberSupplement = string.Empty,
        City = string.Empty,
        State = string.Empty,
        ZipCode = "48386",
    },
    Phone = string.Empty,
    Name = string.Empty,
};
```

And...

```
public class GetUserOnlineProfileRequest
{
    public string? ContractAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public ServiceAddress? Address { get; set; }
    public string? Phone { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int AccountLimit { get; set; } = 10;
}
```

And...

```
public class ServiceAddress
{
    public string? HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string? StreetName { get; set; }
    public string? HouseNumberSupplement { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public string? State { get; set; }
    public string? ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `JsonConvert` from Newtonsoft library. `JsonContent.Create` method uses `System.Text.Json`. These are two different serializers that can produce different results.

Comment: [Migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0) may help you.

Comment: How object is defined? And what server expects? Is there any serialization attributes involved? There is not enough information to guess why it is not working

Comment: Added obj declaration and definition.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thank you! I'll read the migration guide and either post an answer myself or accept the right answer if someone beats me to it.  =)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ok, so I tried JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping JsonSerializationOptions and that WORKED, so I definitely think it has to do with the more aggressive encoding of System.Text.Json.  

Comment: Just calling JsonConent.Create() with JsonSerializerOptions parameter - even if it's the Default - and the call works (200).   

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up the following test to compare the default serialization of the two serializers:

```
[Fact]
public async Task CompareSerializers()
{
    var jsonContent = JsonContent.Create(obj);
    var ms = await jsonContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    var stringContent = new StringContent(json);
    var ns = await stringContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Assert.Equal(ms, ns);
}
```

And this was the result:

ms: `{"contractAccountNumber":"100087751101","ad···`
ns: `{"ContractAccountNumber":"100087751101","Ad···`

The two were identical in every way except that the `System.Text.Json` serializer camelCased the property names, whereas `Newtonsoft.Json` did not.

Strangely, just setting JsonSerializerOptions.Default made the two strings identical.

```
var jsonContent = JsonContent.Create(obj, options: JsonSerializerOptions.Default);
```

ms: `{"ContractAccountNumber":"100087751101","Ad···`
ns: `{"ContractAccountNumber":"100087751101","Ad···`

So, it appears that `JsonContent.Create(obj)` does not use `JsonSerializerOptions.Default` by default.

UPDATE: As expected, this also preserves PascalCase and works with the service I am calling...

```
var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("", obj, options: JsonSerializerOptions.Default);
```